My vite web app not opening on linkendIn and instagram mobile browser
I have a vite app, and i'm trying to promote it on instagram and have attached my link to it.
But the link is not opening in the instagram app inbuilt browser and same for linkendIn only in ios devices.
The link is opening in andriod devices.
my index.html for reference
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/celogosm.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' data:;">
    <title>GeorgeStore</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


